Release dependencies in microservices
The application consists of a JS front and Java Spring backend microservices. most of the time all services are released independently. But sometimes there is a dependence of the backend microservice on the front. Thus, it is necessary to release services in a certain order, or not to release a service if a new version of the service on which it depends has not yet been released. Are there any ways to describe these dependencies and use them during releases?
Tools: gitlab-ci/fluxCD/argoCD, kustomize/Helm (not an umbrella).

That depends heavily on the details of how exactly you're building and deploying the system.  In the case of the front end, your local deployment system can't necessarily update copies of the application that are cached in end users' browsers; keeping compatibility between releases is actually somewhat important in this environment.

I think you need to manage it in your CICD piplelines, so the solution depends on what tools you are using for CICD.

@ArefRiant updated.

@DavidMaze After the front is released, the user receives a new version of the application

in Gitlab CI, if Releases are happening on the same pipeline, you can use:
dependencies: 
  - build:debug
  - build:release

to make a step dependent on another.
if you have multiple pipelines
you can't create dependency by writing the state of your first pipeline in a filesystem or key-value storage and checking it in your second pipeline.
if you can't handle it, getting a DevOps consulting service could be good.
